# Tank does not shoot instantiated bullet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started making a simple game in Unity3d: a tank to shoot at a wall (see image).

[image]

A `GameObject` is attached to the turret of the tank, and to this `GameObject` is attached the following script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Shooter : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody bullet;
    public float power = 1500f;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {

            Rigidbody bulletRB = Instantiate (bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
            bulletRB.AddForce(fwd*power);
        }
    }
}
```

When I press on the Fire1 button the bullet does not shoot. I put (for test) a `Debug.Log("BULLET SHOOT")` after `bulletRB.addForce()`. The message is displayed, so the script reached this point. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Couple of things first, do you see the bullet in the scene hierarchy? Place a test script on the bullet with a Debug in the Awake to see if it actually gets created. You can place another debug in OnDestroy to see if it gets destroyed. You are creating the bullet at the tank position, maybe it is hitting something and destroying itself before it can leave the spot. I would suggest to place a game object at the end of the muzzle and attach it to the tank. You can use its transform.forward for the bullet direction.

Comment: Here because i wanted to see a Tank shoot at a wall

Comment: @fafase - Your answer is ok.Tkx

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this somewhat similar question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/140059/instantiate-rigidbody-c.html) on Unity Answers, you should probably be instantiating the `GameObject` of the bullet prefab/instance, rather than its `Rigidbody` directly. Then, access the `Rigidbody` component of that new bullet and add the force.

Your adjusted `Update()` method would then look like:

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {
        GameObject newBullet = Instantiate (bullet.gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;

        RigidBody bulletRB = newBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        bulletRB.AddForce(fwd*power);
    }
}
```

Another thing you may want to change is using `transform.forward` (aka. Forward vector of the turret) rather than `Vector3.forward` (global forward vector `Vector3(0, 0, 1)`, which may not match the direction of the turret).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I solved itin  this simple way: I attached the shooter script to a GObj, child of the cannon. Tkx for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Force can be applied only to an active rigidbody. **If a GameObject is inactive, AddForce has no effect.**

Wakes up the Rigidbody by default. If the force size is zero then the Rigidbody will not be woken up.

The above description is taken from [Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

**Therefore, I would suggest to check if the GameObject is active first.**

You can test it by doing the following:

```
if (newBullet.activeInHierarchy === true)
{
  //active
}else{
  //inactive
}
```